# Formatting the elements of tuples within a given list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
guest_list = [('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]

for guests in guest_list:          #guests is a tuple
    for x in range(0, len(guests)):
        res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(guests[x], guests[x+1], guests[x+2])
        print(res)
    guests += 1
```

I am trying to format elements of each tuple as `"Ken is 30 years old and works as Chef"`. But in the output, I am getting it done only for the first tuple (instead of all of them). I am not able to pinpoint the exact the spot where I am going wrong.

Comment: Remove the second loop and `guests += 1`, change all `x` to 0.

Comment: Just remove for loop, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the most compact solution. You unpack the tuple directly at the iteration and use an f-string to format it directly:

```
for name, age, job in guest_list: 
    print(f"{name} is {age} years old and works as {job}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do --

```
    def guest_list(guests):
        for name, age, role in guests:
            print("{name} is {age} years old and works as {role}".format(name = name, age = str(age), role = role))
```

However, the following code (although obviously redundant) gives me more of a "visual (in my head) representation" of what I'm trying to accomplish, before removing some extra lines that Python can take care of you

```
    def guest_list(guests):
        i = 0
        for name, age, role in guests:
            name, age, role = guests[i]
            i += 1
            print("{name} is {a`enter code here`ge} years old and works as {role}".format(name = name, age = str(age), role = role))
```

Comment: 1.) Python version 3.8 is already out there. Consider using f-strings. 2.) Your *obviously redundant* code may be irritating and is, ahem, *obviously redundant*. Apart from that, good first answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def guest_list(guests):
    for guest in guests:
        name, age, role = guest
        print("{} is {} years old and works as {}".format(name,str(age),role))

guest_list([('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")])

#Click Run to submit code
"""
Output should match:
Ken is 30 years old and works as Chef
Pat is 35 years old and works as Lawyer
Amanda is 25 years old and works as Engineer
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a nested loop. Just do this:

```
guest_list = [('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]

for guests in guest_list:          #guests is a tuple
    res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(guests[0], guests[1], guests[2])
    print(res)
```

Result:

```
Ken is 30 years old and works as Chef.
Pat is 35 years old and works as Lawyer.
Amanda is 25 years old and works as Engineer.
```

Answer (score 0):

using tuple unpacking.

```
guest_list = [('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]

for guests in guest_list:      
    # tuple unpacking..
    res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(*guests)
    print(res)
```

Comment: It's much clearer to unpack into named variables as part of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner loop at all!
`guest_list` is a list of tuples and `guests` is a tuple as you have clearly mentioned, your last line increments `guests` by 1. You cannot increment a tuple by 1.The inner loop will first have the value of `x` as 0, then it will format `guests[x], guests[x+1], guests[x+2]` as `guests[0], guests[1], guests[3]`.
But in the second iteration, x will have a value of 1, then x+1, x+2 will be 3 and 4 and `guests[4]` does not exist.

You need something like this:

```
guest_list = [('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]

for guests in guest_list:         
    res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(guests[0], guests[1], guests[2])
    print(res)
```

You can also use f-strings like this:

```
for guests in guest_list:
    res = f"{guests[0]} is {guests[1]} years old and works as {guests[2]}.")
    print(res)
```

Another approach would be to use a list comprehension, you'll end up with a list of results.

```
res = [f"{guests[0]} is {guests[1]} years old and works as {guests[2]}.") for guests in guest_list]
map(print, res)
```

The `map()` function applies the print function to each element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have some extraneous code but additionally, you'd benefit from using fstrings. Together, they'd make your code much more readable.

```
guest_list = [('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]

for guest in guest_list:
    print(f"{guest[0]} is {guest[1]} years old and works as {guest[2]}.")
```

```
Ken is 30 years old and works as Chef.
Pat is 35 years old and works as Lawyer.
Amanda is 25 years old and works as Engineer.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def guest_list(guests):
    for name, age, job in guests:
        
        print("{} is {} years old and works as {}".format(name,age,job))

guest_list([('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")])

#Click Run to submit code
"""
Output should match:
Ken is 30 years old and works as Chef
Pat is 35 years old and works as Lawyer
Amanda is 25 years old and works as Engineer
"""
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged. Please try to explain how you got to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def guest_list(guests):
    for name,age,experience in guests:
    
        print("{} is {} years old and works as {}".
format(name,age,experience))

guest_list([('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, 
"Engineer")])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setup_guests(guest_list):
    # loop over the guest list and add each guest to the dictionary with
    # an initial value of 0
    result = {} # Initialize a new dictionary 
    for guest in guest_list: # Iterate over the elements in the list 
        result[guest]= 0 # Add each list element to the dictionary as a key 
        # the starting value of 0
    return result

guests = ["Adam","Camila","David","Jamal","Charley","Titus","Raj","Noemi","Sakira","Chidi"]
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution unpacks the list.

```
def guest_list(guests): 
    for guests in guests:
        name,age,job=guests
        res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(name, age, job) 
        print(res)
```